# VirtualBox claims a USB drive, but hosted CentOS 7 cannot access it

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1, virtualbox, centos

How can I get CentOS 7 to open a USB hard drive from within VirtualBox running inside Windows 8.1?  I have VirtualBox installed in Windows 8.1 and I am using it to launch and use CentOS 7 within VirtualBox.

When I insert the USB drive, VirtualBox is able to "claim" it when I click `Devices > USB Devices > Device Name`, so that a check mark gets added next to Device Name in VirtualBox, while also causing a system sound, and also causing Windows Explorer to stop seeing the usb drive, so that the USB drive disappears from Windows Explorer and is marked in VirtualBox as selected.  I can reverse this by unchecking the USB drive in a similar manner.

The problem is that the CentOS 7 installation inside VirtualBox cannot seem to see the USB drive.  The USB device itself is an [Apricorn SATA Wire 3.0](http://www.apricorn.com/sata-wire-3.html) connector to the hard drive from a dead PC that had CentOS 7 and Windows 7 installed in a dual boot fashion.  I want to access the data from the CentOS partition of the old hard drive using the CentOS 7 running inside VirtualBox on the new PC.

**Now that VirtualBox can see the USB device, how can I get CentOS 7 to see and manipulate the USB device?**

Comment: It should just show up, maybe you should try re-installing virtual box?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Virtualbox host, open settings -> ports -> USB the second icon on the right with the small plus sign.

   - Select the USB device you want to use.
   - Disconnect and reconnect the device.
2. If that doesn't work, using the above settings:

   - disconnect the USB device,
   - shutdown the virtual machine
   - start the virtual machine and wait for it to load
   - insert the USB device
3. Last resort, still with the steps at 1

   - unmount the device from windows and try to mount it from virtualbox's guest window at the bottom (the small usb connector icon)

For me, it usually works with step 2.

Comment: Thank you.  But those three options do not work.  I even uninstalled and reinstalled both VirtualBox and CentOS.  This is holding up work that I need to do in CentOS with files from the old hard drive.

Comment: This may sound lot of work, but did you consider running an Ubuntu (or whatever) Live distro from a different usb stick and run a guest OS in it? If it works, you can at least extract your data from the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I recently succeeded in accessing my USB device on CentOS. Here are my notes:

1. Early versions of VirtualBox needed the VirtualBox extension pack installed. I have heard that the newer VirtualBox versions have USB support built in. I installed the extension pack anyway.
2. On my host device (in my case, a Mac desktop), I ran VirtualBox with elevated privileges. For a Linux/Mac machine, this means invoking VirtualBox from the command line using `sudo`. Because I used a Mac, the command was `sudo open -a VirtualBox.app`.
3. I created a vboxusers group and added myself to it.
4. I enabled USB 1.0 in the settings of the virtual machine. I didn't have any success with USB 2.0 or 3.0. I was only able to observe a mount with USB 1.0 enabled.
5. I installed/upgraded the Guest additions on the CentOS virtual machine.
6. With the VM running and the USB mounted, I selected the USB device I was targeting from the `Devices > USB` menu. Later, I enabled the USB device for the VM permanently by adding a filter for it in the USB settings.
7. Even with the mount, my target program wasn't able to deal with the USB until I ran it with elevated privileges (in my case `sudo hw_server`).

Use `lsutil` on your VM to see if your mount comes up.

Because I've done this process only once, I don't know which of these steps are essential. Hopefully, something in this list will complete your configuration.